# Python - slice array until certain condition is met

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I need to slice an array from a given index until a certain condition is met.

```
>>> a = numpy.zeros((10), dtype='|S1')
>>> a[2] = 'A'
>>> a[4] = 'X'
>>> a[8] = 'B'
>>> a
array(['', '', 'A', '', 'X', '', '', '', 'B', ''], dtype='|S1')
```

For instance, for the above array I want a subset from a given index until first non-zero values in both directions. For example, for index values 2, 4, 8 the results would be:

```
['', '', A, '']      # 2
['', X, '', '', '']  # 4
['', '', '', B, '']  # 8
```

Any suggestions on the simplest way to do this using the numpy API? Learning python and numpy, would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you mean "until first non-None values in both directions"?

Comment: The fact that you are using `object` arrays (not very common and not very memory-efficient) presents a particular problem when trying to determine the index of non-None array items.  Could you be persuaded to use a fixed-byte dtype?  If you are committed to the `object` dtype, then is it true that anything "non-None" will evaluate to `True` when typecast as a `bool`?  Either of those would help simplify things a lot.

Comment: @Paul I am using an `object` array to store single character strings. Essentially, all I need is a `char` array. Is there an alternative `dtype` I could use `dtype`?

Comment: @armandino:  Use `dtype='|S1'` (or simply `dtype=str`) for single-character strings.

Comment: @armandino: Also, if you didn't already notice, you'll probably want numpy.zeros(...) instead of numpy.empty(...) when using `dtype='S1'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is a work for masked arrays, numpy.ma has lots of functions for working with subsets.

```
a = np.zeros((10), dtype=str)
a[2] = 'A'
a[4] = 'X'
a[8] = 'B'
```

let's mask out not empty elements:

```
am=np.ma.masked_where(a!='', a)
```

`np.ma.notmasked_contiguous` goes through the array (very efficiently) and finds all the slices of contiguous elements where the array is not masked:

```
slices = np.ma.notmasked_contiguous(am)
[slice(0, 1, None), slice(3, 3, None), slice(5, 7, None), slice(9, 9, None)]
```

so, the array is continuously empty between element 5 and 7 for example.
Now you only have to join the slices you are interested in, first you get the starting index of each slice:

```
slices_start = np.array([s.start for s in slices])
```

then you get the location of the index you are looking for:

```
slices_start.searchsorted(4) #4
Out: 2
```

So you want slice 1 and 2:
    a[slices[1].start:slices[2].stop+1]
    array(['', 'X', '', '', ''], 
      dtype='|S1')

or let's try 8:

```
i = slices_start.searchsorted(8)
a[slices[i-1].start:slices[i].stop+1]
Out: array(['', '', '', 'B', ''], 
  dtype='|S1')
```

If should probably play a bit with this in ipython for understanding it better.

Comment: Very interesting Andrea. Thanks for the explanations. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

If you set up your problem like this:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.zeros((10), dtype=str)
a[2] = 'A'
a[4] = 'X'
a[8] = 'B'
```

You can easily get the indices of non-empty strings like so:

```
i = numpy.where(a!='')[0]  # array([2, 4, 8])
```

Alternatively, `numpy.argwhere(..)` also works well.

Then you can slice away using this array:

```
out2 = a[:i[1]]        # 2   ['' '' 'A' '']
out4 = a[i[0]+1:i[2]]  # 4   ['' 'X' '' '' '']
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks Paul. That looks like what I'm after.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this could be cleanly done in pure python using itertools and functools.

```
import functools, itertools
arr = ['', '', 'A', '', 'X', '', '', '', 'B', '']

f = functools.partial(itertools.takewhile, lambda x: not x)
def g(a, i):
    return itertools.chain(f(reversed(a[:i])), [a[i]], f(a[i+1:]))
```

We define f as the sub-iterator found by looking until the element evaluates as true, and g as the combination of applying this on the reversed area of the list before the index and the list after the index.

This returns generators which can be casted to lists that contain our results.

```
>>> list(g(arr, 2))
['', '', 'A', '']
>>> list(g(arr, 4))
['', 'X', '', '', '']
>>> list(g(arr, 8))
['', '', '', 'B', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

Two loops are the first thing that comes to mind.  Something like this would work:

```
'''Given an array and an index...'''
def getNoneSlice(a, i):

    # get the first non-None index before i
    start = 0
    for j in xrange(i - 1, -1, -1):
        if a[j] is not None: # or whatever condition
            start = j + 1
            break

    # get the first non-None index after i
    end = len(a) - 1
    for j in xrange(i + 1, len(a)):
        if a[j] is not None: # or whatever condition
            end = j - 1
            break

    # return the slice
    return a[start:end + 1]
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. The solution works perfectly (+1). I was hoping however there would be a `numpy` method for something like this.

Comment: I downvoted because this is very inefficient for large sparse arrays.  Use the numpy methods of the other answers.

Comment: Yes, Steabert, agreed...  At least I learned something new :-P

Answer (score -2):

```
def getSlice(a, n):
    try:
        startindex = a[:n].nonzero()[0][-1]
    except IndexError:
        startindex = 0
    try:
        endindex = a[(n+1):].nonzero()[0][0] + n+1
    except IndexError:
        endindex = len(a)
    return a[startindex: endindex]
```

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work. I get `['' 'A']
['' 'X']
['' 'B']
`

Comment: The question didn't have empty strings in it when I answered it, it had 'None'. It the nonzero method works with 'None'.